# How to Put Data in Range in one statement

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I want to put my data in a Range like below.

```
 SpreadsheetGear.IRange cells = worksheet.Cells[A1:Z1];
```

Where A1 = 1, B1 = 2,......,Z1 = 26

I want to do this with one statement, such as:

```
cells.values = [1,2,3,...26] //Object
```

and not with one statement per value.

The result should be 
A1 = 1,
B1 = 2,
.
.
.
.
.
Z1 = 26

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

it's simple:

```
object[] arr = new object[,] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };

cells.values = arr;
```

array length must be same as range;

Comment: The array needs to be 2D.  For example:object[,] array = new object[,] { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };